# How to publish a single node file that contains a few Express endpoints

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Since I still don't have the actual API endpoints I'm going to use in my Angular project , I'm currently working with javascript file (containing some fake api endpoints created using Express), which I later run using a npm command like this:

```
  "scripts": {        
    "server": "ts-node -P ./server/server.tsconfig.json ./server/server.ts",
  },
```

This is the content of the `server.tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017"]
  }
}
```

And the content of the `server.ts`, has the following structure.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { Application } from 'express';

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app: Application = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// .....

// ACCOUNT

app.route('/api/account/login').post((req, res) => {
  console.log(`Login Endpoint`);
  res.status(200).send({
    email: 'bob@test.com',
    displayName: 'Bob',
    token:
      'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c',
  });
});



app.route('/api/account/emailexists').get((req, res) => {
  console.log('emailexists' + req.query.email);

  const { email } = req.query;
  if (email === 'bob@test.com') {
    res.status(200).send({ email });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(null);
  }
});

// .....

const httpServer: any = app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log(
    'HTTP REST API Server running at http://localhost:' +
      httpServer.address().port
  );
});
```

I need this endpoints running in separate url. I've got zero experience publishing node/express applications , but I've got an amazon account where a publish my angular projects.

Do you have any idea how can I publish these simple files so that I can have access to the endpoint it contains? The information I've found is really confusing.

Thanks

Comment: Base on the question and your tagging, I believe you have no prior experience deploying a server application. S3 will not help you as it's for static content only ( Angular )
You will have to go with the server side technologies to host your serverside code. The simple option would be Elastic BeanStalk, followed by EC2 and Lambda

Comment: Is it using Elastic BeanStalk  as easy as using S3 or more complicated? I mean, for my use case.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated whenever it comes to setting up the serverside but not to say it is not doable for someone without experience. It should takes 1 or 2 workdays if you follow correctly the common instructions available on the web